# Учебник химии

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно сказать "учебник химии" или "учебник по химии", "справочник орфографии" или "справочник по орфографии"?

Answer (score 1):

Справочник- книга, которая обеспечивает справку ПО какому-либо вопросу. Справочник по орфографии.
Пособие = помощь кому-то в чём-то. Пособие по орфографии.
Учебник - книга для изучения чего-то. Учебник алгебры.

Comment: Оно так, но автор, как я понимаю, таким вряд ли не удовлетворится, если это, конечно, не иностранный студент. Хочется понять, по чем такое положение мотивировано.  
Кчебник, кстати, вполне может быть и "по". "Учебник по основам безопасности жизнедеятельности", например. "Учебник основ безопасности жизнедеятельности" язык принимать отказывается просто по причине троекратного родительного (хотя и двукратный - уже перебор).

Answer (score 0):

Справчник точно - "по химии". Иначе это что-то странное получится. "Справчник, принадлежащий химии".
Вот с учебником - сложнее. Строгих запретов учебнику быть "по" нет, но стилистически точнее "Учебник химии". Учителю, кстати, тоже логичнее быть "учителем химии" а не "по химии". "По" и учибнику, и учителю придает характер какой-то выборочности, частичности, незавершонности преподаваемого курса науки. Сравните: "лектор по естественно-научным дисциплинам" или "совет внешнеполитичесим воросам". Это не по всему спектру упоминаемых предметов, это избранный, актуальные и т.п.